# Constraint - SWI- Prolog Queries

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have an exam coming up and I'm going through past papers to help my understanding.

I came across the following past paper question:

**Consider the following queries and answers. Some answers coincide with
what SWI-Prolog would infer whereas others are erroneous. Indicate which
answers are genuine and which ones are fake (no explanation of your answer
is required).**

```
(i) |?- [A, B, C] ins 0 .. 2, A #= B + C.

A = 0..2 B = 0..2 C = 0..2

(ii) |?- A in 0 .. 3, A * A #= A.

A = 0..2

(iii) |?- [A, B] ins -1 .. 1, A #= B.

A = 1 B = 1

(iv) |?- [A, B] ins 0 .. 3, A #= B + 1.

A = 1..3 B = 1..2
```

I'm struggling to see how each one is either true or false. Would someone be able to explain to me how to figure these out please.

Thank you, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

The key principle for deciding which answers are admissible and which are not is to look whether the residual program is declaratively **equivalent** to the original query. If the residual constraints admit any solution that the original query does not, or the other way around, then the answer is fake (or you have found a mistake in the CLP(FD) solver). If the shown answer is not even syntactically valid, then the answer is *definitely* fake.

Let's do it:

1. (i) `|?- [A, B, C] ins 0 .. 2, A #= B + C.`

   suggested answer: `A = 0..2 B = 0..2 C = 0..2`

   **WRONG**! The original query constrains the variables to *integers*, but this answer is not even a syntactically valid Prolog program.
2. (ii) `|?- A in 0 .. 3, A * A #= A.`

   suggested answer: `A = 0..2`

   **WRONG!** The original query constrains `A` to *integers*, but according to this residual program, `A = 0..2` is a valid solution. The term `..(0, 2)` is not an integer.
3. (iii) `|?- [A, B] ins -1 .. 1, A #= B.`

   suggested answer: `A = 1 B = 1`

   **WRONG**! Not syntactically valid.
4. (iv) `|?- [A, B] ins 0 .. 3, A #= B + 1.`

   suggested answer: `A = 1..3 B = 1..2`

   **WRONG**! Not syntactically valid.

Note that even if all shown answers were syntactically valid *and* `=/2` were replaced by `in/2` in the residual goals of (i), (ii) and (iv), these answer would *still* be all wrong, because you can in each case find solutions that either are not admissible by the original query or the residual goals, but not both. I leave solving these cases as an exercise for you, for example, suppose the respective answers are:

1. `A in 0..2, B in 0..2, C in 0..2.`
2. `A in 0..2.`
3. `A = 1, B = 1.`
4. `A in 1..3, B in 1..2.`

and find a witness for each case to show that the residual goals are semantically different from the respective original query.

For example, in case (1), `A = B = C = 2` would be a valid solution according to the residual constraints, but obviously the original constraints exclude this solution, because `2 #= 2 + 2` does *not* hold!

Comment: mmmh... actually, the question doesn't mention residuals. For case i), I get `A = 0..2 B = 0..2 C = 0..2` *and* the residual `B+C#=A`.

Comment: For case (i), you get the residual goals `A in 0..2, B in 0..2, C in 0..2` and `B+C#=A`. This is declaratively equivalent to the original query. If you only got `A in 0..2, B in 0..2, C in 0..2`, then the residual program would be incorrectly *more general* than the original query. The residual program must always be declaratively equivalent to the original query, If you get `A = 0..2` among other residual, then `A` is not even an integer but the term `0..2`. If, as in `A = 0..2 B = 0..2`, the answer is not even syntactically valid, then it is definitely fake.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is always restricted to get a value contained in its domain, and arithmetic constrains only reduce the domain of involved variables.

So, try to 'label' all variables - that is, assign values from answers reported domains. Of course, if the arithmetic relation is not satisfied, you can say the answer is faked. Take ii). Does it hold for A=0 ? What about A=2 ?

This 'test' of course doesn't suffice to answer all questions. Some reported domains are narrower. For instance, take iii). Can you see any reason that excludes -1, or 0. If you cannot, you should mark the answer as faked.